# SwiftUI NavigationView showing ActionSheet, Popover, or Sheet in child view dismisses child view

Tags: ios, swiftui, ipados

On iPad, when I have a navigation hierarchy presented in a similar style to the following:

```
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hi").actionSheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) { () -> ActionSheet in
                ActionSheet(title: Text("welllllll"))
            },
                           tag: true,
                           selection: $didNavigateToChild) {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.didNavigateToChild = true
                            }) {
                                Text("Let's go!")
                            }
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

By the time the popover, actionsheet, or sheet are presented (in this case, the `ActionSheet` with text "welllllll") the child view is dismissed (`Text("Hi")`) and I end up back at `Text("Let's go!")`.

I've been trying to catch what's calling this dismissal, but I'm new to SwiftUI and my old symbolic breakpoints are failing me.

For whatever reason, this only occurs on iPad. Presenting `ActionSheet` and `Sheet` from child `NavigationView`s works just fine on iPhone without any weird navigation side effects.

Comment: Works fine on a Simulator with iOS 14 beta.

Comment: @pawello2222 my `Text("Hi")` is a view showing a `MKMapView` and on iOS 13.7 and Xcode 11.7 it absolutely navigates "back" every time an ActionSheet or Popover is shown on the `MKMapView` . It's totally fine when an annotation is shown on the map, but adding a popover shoots me back a view and I'm not sure which symbol to break on in order to catch the dismissal in SwiftUI.

Comment: @pawello2222 - I tested with Xcode 12 GM and you're correct, it totally works. The problem I have is that the view is significantly complex and the `.popover` or `.actionSheet` I was adding to the MapView's annotation was actually being performed on the mapview itself. Once the popover or actionsheet was shown over the complex view I believe since it was covering (a small portion of) it, it was having disappear called which would cause the parent view containing the map to disappear but leaving the actionsheet or popover on the screen. I think it's both my fault and a weird bug in swiftui.

Comment: So, I found a weird bug when having a significantly complex hierarchy using `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink`s. While in an empty project, and using this setup it works, in my project as soon as the SwiftUI `.popover` or `.actionsheet` view modifier appears, the transition view it places on the screen causes the root view to get recreated. As soon as I'm done with this project I'll be creating an example project and filing a bug, but for now my workaround is to use a UIHostingController and display my own popover made in the UIKit fashion.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue in my project. Showing an action sheet causes the navigation to pop to root. All works fine in iOS 13 but the issue is with iOS 14. I am unable to find a solution so far, so if you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: @ThomasVos This is exactly the issue. My assumption was that the transition view that gets created (sometimes with an incredibly weird frame) is causing the underlying `NavigationView` to have onDisappear called.
I ended up creating my own popover that conforms to `UIViewControllerRepresentable` and using that in a `UIHostingController`. Presenting the popover this way for whatever reason seems to work.